# How might I be able to use Array.prototype.forEach on an object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm just trying to make a little framework for learning purposes, and I want to be able to use `Array.prototype.forEach` on objects, this is what I have right now,

```
var data = { test: 'test' };

Array.prototype.forEach(data, function(key value) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

But I get an error, I'm sure you guys can see why, but I can not :) So any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: I'd assume the "Why?" is because an object isn't an array. You also have a syntax error in the parameters in your anonymous function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects are not arrays, and don't have access to the array prototype.  You can just loop over the properties.

```
for(var key in data){
      console.log(key) //or data[key] if you want the values
   }
```

with regards to the jQuery comment below, it appears they use loops internally for their "each" function.  From the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js):

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var value,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj );

    if ( args ) {
        if ( isArray ) {
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else {
        if ( isArray ) {
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
},
```

Comment: This works, I just thought that jQuery did it with their $.each function using the foreach prototype

Comment: I think you are confusing the forEach method of Array with the for-in loop

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, Object and Array are different things. You can create a function that will do this for you, by using "call" for invocation:

```
Object.prototype.forEach = function(func, context) {
    var value;
    context = context || this;  //apply the function to 'this' by default
    for (key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  //to rule out inherited properties
            value = this[key];
            func.call(context, key, value);
        }
    }    
};
```

And use it like this:

```
obj = { "test1": 1, "test2": 2 };
obj.forEach(function(key, val) { 
    console.log(key, val); 
});
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Can someone explain the problem with this approach? Imagine if you needed to parse a massive JSON blob filled with arrays. Using a .forEach on an array inside of a for ... in loop will cause any JS linter to throw a fit. And using nested for ... in loops gets nasty very quickly since all variables declared will be scoped to the surrounding function.

Comment: The key and value parameter should probably be inverted to match the Array forEach prototype

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(data[key])
});
```

*You can shim `Object.keys()` for old browsers if needed.*

---

If you prefer, you can make a wrapper function for this operation:

```
function objEach(obj, fn) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        fn(obj[key], key)
    })
    // or use for-in
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
objEach(data, function(val, key) {
    console.log(key, val)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

With ES2017, there is [`Object.entries()`](https://mdn.io/Object.entries):

```
const obj = { 0:'value1', key:'value2' };

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

For ES5, there is [`Object.keys()`](https://mdn.io/Array.keys):

```
const obj = { 0:'value1', key:"value2" };

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

If your object is Array-like (meaning that it has numerical keys and a `length`), there is ES2015's [`Array.from()`](https://mdn.io/Array.from):

```
const obj = { 0:'value1', 1:'value2', length:2 };

Array.from(obj).forEach((element, i) => {
    console.log(i, element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the objects keys by `for(key in data)` and get each value by `data[key]`. I.e.

```
for(key in object) {
    console.log(key, data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
obj = {}; // Some object
obj.forEach = function(fn) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach((k)=> {
        if (typeof(this[k]) != 'function') 
            fn(this[k]);})
        };
```